# how to add input type in this javascript file

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I am creating webview for an Android appication. I dont know how to use input tag of HTML in this code.

```
 var path;

    var confirmDelete = function(p) {
        path = p;
        $.prompt("Do You Want To Delete", {
            buttons : {
                "YES" : true,
                "NO" : false
            },

            callback : deleteCallback
        });
        return false;
    }

    function deleteCallback(e, v, m, f) {
        if (v != undefined && v == true) {
            var loc = window.location.pathname + path;
            $.post(loc, {}, function(data) {
                $.prompt(data, {
                    buttons : {
                        "OK" : true
                    },
                    callback : deletedCallback
                });
            });
        }
        return false;
    }

    function deletedCallback(e, v, m, f) {
        window.location.reload();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific and explain with elaborated example such as images?

Comment: i am creating an application in which user can access their android SD card to pc .so i am creating a webview. user can rename his sd card file or filder through this java script file . i want a user input box here .how can i set user inpur in this javascript code . sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

If "$" in your code is referring to jQuery, then just

```
$("body").append("<input class='myinput' type='text' name='myinput' />");
```

will create input for you.